# Highcharts How to toggle DataLabel

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I've got a chart with two series. I want to toggle the dataLabels of the series by clicking a button.

```
changeDatalabel(): void { 

if (!this.dataLabelEnabled) { // global Var
  this.chart.ref.series[0].update({ dataLabels: { enabled: true } }); // Compile error
  this.dataLabelEnabled = true; // for toggling
} else {
  this.chart.ref.series[0].update({ dataLabels: { enabled: false } }); // Compile error
  this.dataLabelEnabled = false; // for toggling
}
```

The problem is that the updateMethod get a compile error when I insert "dataLabels: {enable: true}" and he is jumping out of the method "changeDatalabel()".

When i got two buttons with the updateMethod the compile error turn up again but it works.

```
createLabel(): void {
this.chart.ref.series[0].update({ dataLabels: { enabled: true } });



deleteLabel(): void {
this.chart.ref.series[0].update({ dataLabels: { enabled: false } });
```

Comment: What kind of error do you receive? See the example for dynamic interaction with the chart https://github.com/gevgeny/angular2-highcharts#dynamic-interaction-with-chart-object. If you still have problem with your example, paste the full component code or create a live example, e.g. on plunkr

Comment: @morganfree the funny thing is in the fiddle i created it works. but in my application not. Error: "Argument of type '{dataLabels: {enabled: boolean;};' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dataLabels' does not exist in type 'IndividualSeriesOptions'.


https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8a1dy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the issue with the correct types. You can see in [@types/highcharts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/highcharts/index.d.ts) that the `series.update` first param is of `IndividualSeriesOptions` type which dooes not have `DataLabels` prop.

You can set the options type explicitly to be of `LineChart` type:

```
import { LineChart } from 'highcharts';
...

toggleLabel(): void {
  const options: LineChart = {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: !this.dataLabelEnabled
    }
  }

  this.chart.ref.series[0].update(options);
  this.dataLabelEnabled = !this.dataLabelEnabled;
}
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmhomi?file=app/highchart-demo/highchart-demo.component.ts

Comment: This is amazing! Doesn't know that this works. Thank you very much.